# Is there a way to get CSS/XPath from a Capybara Element?

Tags: css, xpath, capybara

Is there a way to get CSS/XPath from a Capybara Element?

I tried, #path - http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara%2FNode%2FSimple%3Apath but that does not seem to work.

I am running it on Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: Your link is to Capybara::Node::Simple which doesn't use a driver; but you say you're using Selenium Webdriver.  Is the link wrong?

Comment: I meant this link : http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#path-instance_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
query = element.instance_variable_get(:@query) <br>
locator = query.locator <br>
format = query.selector.format
```

Answer (score 1):

Capybara 2.5 has been released now:

The master branch of Capybara supports #path with selenium - it'll be released as version 2.5 soon.